# initialize() not work with @Deprecated in FXML Manager after doing an update

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, initialization, deprecated

I work with (FXML Manager in intellij idea 2022.2)
When I update the control file using the "update controller from FXML" option,  I get a "@Deprecated" instead of "@FXML" on initialize() method,and that does not allow the method to be run.
Thus, I always change the "@Deprecated" to "@FXML" in order for the method to work.
Q: Is there a solution to avoid this repetition ?
thank you.

Comment: Read about `Controllers` [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: I was trying to work out what FXMLManager was because ai have never heard of it. It is [this third party idea plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14854-fxmlmanager)

Comment: The plugin documentation notes that it will “@Deprecate all ActionEvent methods that are missing in FXML”, but it should not also deprecate the initialize method.  I suggest you contact the plugin author directly. You are unlikely to get any assistance on StackOverflow.

Comment: For reference, [`Initializable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) notes that the "interface has been _superseded_," not deprecated, and it must be "suitably annotated" to be useful.